# Show a hidden element or change the behaviour on the link element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I got a link in the navigation with a icon in it. The icon itself is a animation with a + to x. Now in the x state I would like for the user to be able to "close" with a click on the icon/text. Now I'm not sure what is the best approach here.

1. to have a hidden element showing when the animation is done with the transition to x and hide this
2. add a class to the link so it triggers a `$state.transitionTo('state')` to the wanted url
3. suggestion

[you can check it here at my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X5owzXO5eYbiVgJl7AMF?p=preview)

Comment: how are you animating?

Comment: it actually not a animation, just a transition with css @kabaehr

Answer (score 0):

`<nav ng-class="{'1': 'nav rotate'}[myVar]">
    <a ui-sref="home" class="nav__home">Home</a>
    <a ng-click="myVar == '1' ? myVar ='0' : myVar = '1'" ui-sref="random" class="nav__random" >
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> random
    </a>
  </nav>`

Comment: can you provide a explanation?